# Classifying 8 objects based on 3 attributes

Tags: classification

I had 8 objects and asked 80 people to score them on three attributes, say A, B, and C. Now I want to check if these 8 objects can be classified into categories based on the similarity between the scores they received on those three attributes.

Do you know any methods in R or SPSS that can do this task?

Comment: You should elaborate bit more. I have no idea what object is here. Seems like n = 80 and each subject rates on item A, B, and C. Where does this 8 object kick in?

Comment: Hi @won782: basically these 8 objects were 8 different persons described in my research. We asked people to rate these 8 different persons based on 3 characteristics (for instance: kindness, generosity, and openness). Even though it wasn't anticipated in the research, we now need to know if these 8 people can be categorized into a few categories based on the score people gave them on those three characteristics. Those categories do not exist and we are curious to see if anything emerges from this analysis. Given my background I am very far from this methodology to master quickly.

Comment: What "categories" are you referring to? Do you wonder if you can identify Alice, Bob, Charlene, etc., uniquely from their scores on A, B, & C? (That's what people usually mean by "classification".)

Comment: Note that question just seeking code or software help are generally off topic here.

Comment: @gung: Yes, I realized that it's off topic and already feel bad about it... sorry! will delete it...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to check if you are able to distinguish these 8 persons using only the 3 features you have chosen.

For this kind of problem I would "melt" the data creating dataset with 4 columns: `feature A`, `feature B`, `feature C`, `person ID` (target variable). In the next step I would try to find the best apporach. As you probably research in psychology I think using a decision tree would be very informative.

One big issue is that using this approach you would not utilize e.g. the information about raters themselves. Meaning that people are diffrent. One likes to give everybody high rates, the other one - low. Therefore some standardization of the scores would be nice. I don't know your scale but e.g. you could calculate z-scores within every feature but only for one rater. I don't know if there is a gold standard in this scenario.

You probably should also assess inter-rater consistency using e.g. intra-class correlation coefficient, maybe Cohen's kappa or Bland-Altman regression.

If you do not have programming knowledge I wouldn't go with R. I would use WEKA machine learning toolkit; as it is very intuitive and has very good MOOC.